# What is the pattern of the sequence?

Tags: word-problem, pattern-recognition

I am currently working at a math camp filled with tiny math geniuses, and one of them gave me a problem yesterday with which I am having trouble. This problem was written by a fourth grader and has reportedly only been solved on one other occasion. I'm not particularly good with patterns, and I wondered if anyone on this site might have any ideas.

"On Tuesday, it was very rainy, as Jane noticed. In the first minute, there were only 2 drops, while there were 7 drops in the second minute. There were 33 drops in the third minute, but that soon escalated into 266 drops in the fourth minute and eventually 3140 drops in the fifth minute. If this pattern continues, it will be very rainy. Help Jane figure out how many drops fell total in the first ten minutes. Based off your answer, tell Jane whether to play outside or not."

Comment: That's a scary place to be,with 7 year olds who will be at Cal Tech by age 14.

Comment: When you say 2 drops the first minute and 7 the second, etc- do you mean 2 drops total or 2 drops in the first minute fell,etc?

Comment: Given that each term is at least 3 times the previous and the ratio only appears to increase, the last part seems obvious: why would Jane want to play outside when the ground is soaking wet, and there will be a torrential flood within the hour?  On the other hand, maybe it's worth having one last play before the world is indundated with unstoppable rain.

Comment: @ErickWong That QUALITATIVELY answers Jane's dilemma, but it doesn't give a precise answer to how many drops fell in 10 minutes.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Of course, but I'm still free to criticize the conceit of the question that your advice to Jane is predicated on the precise number of drops in ten minutes :).  The question already states that it will be very rainy.

Comment: Are you allowed to hit them?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 I asked my student that same question, and he clarified that during the second minute, 7 drops fell; it's not 7 drops total.

Comment: I read the help center very carefully before posting this question. It was my opinion that it fell into the category of a mathematical puzzle. Just because it was written by a fourth grader who understands college-level math, doesn't make it any less valid of a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The key part to this, in my opinion, is that "**if the pattern continues**, it will continue to be rainy." However, that doesn't mean that the inside beginning part of the pattern is definitely always increasing. Yes, it looks that way from the beginning, but what if it's actually some polynomial that has some twists and turns in the beginning, but then skyrockets after $t=5 \text{ min}$?

We have five points, so [we can fit them exactly into a quartic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit+quartic+for+%7B%7B1,2%7D,%7B2,7%7D,%7B3,33%7D,%7B4,266%7D,%7B5,3140%7D%7D). It kind of loops back and forth between $t=1$ and $t=4$, but then it just skyrockets out. As it turns out, for $t=6,7,8,9,10$, this polynomial yields integer values for $y$ despite the fractional coefficients, so we have:
$$2+7+33+266+3140+13337+37787+85668+168406+299675=608321\text{ drops}$$
Now, you'll notice that the ratios start to mellow out because this is quartic, not exponential, but it is still very rainy, so I think that this is a suitable answer given the problem description.

Comment: Yikes,I never would have considered a least squares fit for a fifth degree polynomial. I SHOULD have,that's how we solve real life applied mathematics problems. But I was thinking there was some closed form summation sequence for the problem that could be arrived at by trial and error.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Using least-squares is how I make up for not being able to recognize complex patterns.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 "That's how we solve real life applied mathematics problems" - Are you sure about that? If someone told me, "I took the data and then extrapolated using the [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)," I would be extremely suspicious of everything they say afterwards (unless it continues as, "I did this to demonstrate that one can obtain any value as part of a pattern" or "I already knew it was a polynomial of degree $4$, I just needed to know which one")

Comment: @MiloBrandt I didn't mean with that comment that particular method. I meant in that instead of looking for an abstract approach in a closed form "equation" solution, I should have considered a numerical one as well.